# Como declarar valores nulos em C

Tags: c, loop, while

Meu problema é o seguinte estou criando um *loop* `while` que não pode receber valores menores ou iguais a zero, e gostaria de declarar também que não pode receber valores vazios para o programa forçar o usuário a digitar um número e não o <kbd>enter</kbd> sem nenhum campo no `scanf()`.

```
  printf("Digite o valor da posicao X:");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    //faz a verificação se o numero é 0 ou < 0
  while (x <= 0){
    printf("0 ou < 0 nao forma um triangulo por favor digite novamente a medida X\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
  }
```

Quando o usuário apenas digita <kbd>enter</kbd> ele aceita sem dado nenhum no console, no caso queria que o sistema aceitasse apenas se um numero estivesse digitado no console.

Comment: Precisa explicar melhor, de preferência com que código está tendo problema. Nulo é uma coisa, vazio é outra, depende do tipo de dado que está lidando. Nulo é 0, mas o `scanf()` não lida com nada que possa ser nulo. Então a pergunta tem premissas erradas e está confusa, precisa especificar melhor pra podermos ajudar.

Comment: Fiz a alteração.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seja isto que deseja. Você verifica se a entrada foi válida, a função `scanf()` provê isto como retorno, é só ler a [documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). E também pode validar a entrada do dado com o valor que desejar. Tudo isso em um simples laço.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x;
    while (scanf("%d", &x) != 0 && x <= 0) printf("0 ou < 0 nao forma um triangulo por favor digite novamente a medida X\n");
    printf("%d", x);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/oGvg9S). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/uesefwqu-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/Validating.c).